# Get absolute path of files using 'find' command

Tags: command-line, find

Is there a way to get absolute path of a file that is being searched?

For example:

```
find .. -name "filename"
```

It gives me results like `../filename` but I want the full path.

What I need is to find in the parent directory and its children, for a specific file, that I will use in another script later.

Thanks

Comment: [Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246215/how-can-i-list-files-with-their-absolute-path-in-linux).

Comment: `find $(readlink -f ..) -name "filename"`. Use readlink in the file path for ease.

Comment: the comment here using `readlink` is the best answer by far, but I'll just add that (1) quotes are important in case there's a space in the dir name, and (2) `realpath` is apparently preferred according to `man readlink(1)`: eg: `find "$(realpath ..)" -name "filename"` (nb: `find ... -printf ...` has no option for this, and `find ... - exec readlink -f {} \;` is suuuuper slow)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use `bash`'s [Tilde Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) to get the absolute path of the current working directory, this way `find` prints the absolute path for the results as well:

```bash
find ~+ -type f -name "filename"
```

If executed in `~/Desktop`, this is expanded to

```bash
find /home/yourusername/Desktop -type f -name "filename"
```

and prints results like:

```bash
/home/yourusername/Desktop/filename
```

If you want to use this approach with the current working directory’s **parent** directory you need to `cd` before calling `find`:

```bash
cd .. && find ~+ -type f -name "filename"
```

Answer (score 39):

Try something like:

```
find "$(cd ..; pwd)" -name "filename"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just testing `$(cd ..; pwd)`. Here it works OK, but if I do it alone in a Terminal, I can't get the parent dir... I get "Bash: <dir>: Is a directory. And if I do `$(cd ..; echo "something")` I get "something: not a command"

Comment: Do you mean like a separate command? Then you would need to leave out the dollar sign: `(cd ..; pwd)`

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Any reference of why should I remove the $, how does it affect the subshell?

Comment: Yes `( ... )` means execute in a subshell, the output gets written to stdout. `$( ... )` stands for "command substitution". The latter can be used as if it were a variable expansion.

Comment: find / -name "filename"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen : That would list every occurrence from the root down, which is not the requirement and which may give wrong results if there are multiples files present with that name, it is also unnecessarily taxing on the system.

Comment: @Scrutinizer - I think you misunderstand how find works. If you use the full path in your search, you get the full path in your output. `find /home/your_user -name foo`. As OP is using "../" , hard to guess the full path to give in an answer.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen If you use `/` then `find` starts looking from the root instead of from the directory that the OP specified. Do you understand what `pwd` does in the suggestion I gave? What is the first character that `pwd` returns?

Comment: @JorgeeFG ```$(builtin cd ..; pwd)``` will canel functions, aliases.

Answer (score 27):

The simplest way is

```
find "$(pwd -P)" -name "filename"
```

Comment: Yes! Or ``find `pwd -P` -name "filename"``

Comment: this will find files in the current directory not from parent.

Comment: @ApollyssupportsMonica nice! but if there are spaces in the path - you need to wrap it in the quotes, so `find "`pwd -P`" -name "..."` is more universal :-)

Answer (score 26):

Try using the `-exec` option of `find`:

```
find .. -name "filename" -exec readlink -f {} \;
```

Note: `readlink` prints the value of a symbolic link or canonical file name.

Comment: this will call readlink on every file so it will be very ineffective.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution but I found `xargs`  to be much faster.............................................. ```find .. -name "filename" | xargs readlink -f```

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me, but will only return the first occurrence.

```
realpath $(find . -type f -name filename -print -quit)
```

To get full paths for all occurrences (as suggested by Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy)

```
find . -type f -name filename -print0 | xargs -0 realpath
```

Comment: Previous comment removed, +1, good job @Wyrmwood

Comment: Exactly what I needed (just the first occurrence and to print the full path including the filename in the output. Thank you Sir

Comment: this doesn't work for files with whitespaces

Comment: @peixotorms `-print0` does the trick, and I corrected the answer.

Comment: `xargs 0` is a feature I have used recently for values with embedded single quotes, Nice@DawnSong

Answer (score 6):

Try this way:

```
find $PWD -name "filename"
```

Comment: The question has `..`, not `.`.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I totally misunderstand, it is as simple as this:

```
find $(realpath .) -name 'river.jpg'
```

By specifying the full real path as a start, find will implicitly output this full path as a search result.

The bash command realpath converts the current (or any other directory as ./images) into its real path). the $(realpath .) converts the output to a variable, as if it was typed manually, e.g. /home/myusername

Answer (score 2):

Try with `-printf`.
This also works with files with blank spaces.

`find .. -name "filename" -printf $PWD/"%f\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Also using PWD can show you the full directory. Pwd will show you all your directorys you are in like the expanding of filename. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Removing last directory component with [parameter Expansion](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#expansion).

```bsh
find "${PWD%/*}" -name 'filename'
```

An example of how you can use [mapfile](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#shell%20builtin%20commands) to save output from find to an indexed array for later use.

```bsh
mapfile -t -d '' < <(find ${PWD%/*} -name 'filename' -print0)
```

(if no array name is specified, MAPFILE will be the default array name).

```bsh
for i in "${MAPFILE[@]}"; do
    echo "$((n++)) $i"
done
```